# Работа с webbrowser c#

Tags: c#

У меня есть текстовый документ с 10 ссылок сайтов.
Я хочу их спарсить. 

Делаю **так**:
Беру первый url с текстового док. и перехожу по нем с веббраузера. 
 
Дальше парсю. Как только процесс парсинга первой  url прошел, начинаю парсить 2 ссылку, и так далее.

Вопрос в том, как мне сделать чтобы можно было парсить сразу 10  url,  а не по одной. (Авторизация на сайте) важная.

Upd.
Немного допишу.

```
 Uri url = new Uri(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()); // закидываю с txt в list box мои url, выбираю 1 url
                webBrowser1.Url = url; // присваиваю браузеру выбранный url
```

Потом сохраняю html код в отдельный txt и его парсю

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument d = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                d.Load(@"HTML.txt");
```

Comment: Предоставьте пожалуйста код, не совсем понятно что конкретно у вас происходит, "Беру первый url с текстового док. и перехожу по нем с веббраузера. Дальше парсю"???

Comment: Апдейтнул. Может так лучше будет...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как я понял можно попробовать так

```
    static class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        string[] urls = File.ReadAllLines("references.txt");
        foreach(var url in urls)
        {
           Magic(GetRequest(url));
        }         
    }

    public static void Magic(string html)
    {
       //Тут вы можете обрабатывать данные страницы 
    }

    public static string GetRequest(string uri)//Get запрос
    {
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

        var dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        webResponse.Close();

        return responseFromServer;
    }
}
```

Подходит если это GET запросы и ссылки в файле references.txt по одной в каждой линии, если нет, используйте Split() c сепаратором.

Comment: https://github.com/Overv/SteamWebAPI

Comment: Спасибо, я видел это. Я не пойму как прикрепить это к вашему коду